# movq and 64 bit numbers

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, att, instruction-set

When I write to a register, everything is fine,

```
movq  $0xffffffffffffffff, %rax
```

But I get Error: operand size mismatch when I write to a memory location,

```
movq  $0xffffffffffffffff, -8(%rbp)
```

Why is that? I see in compiled C code that in asm these numbers are split in two and two movl instructions show up.

Maybe you can tell me where the mowq and other instructions are documented.

Comment: @jww: You missed removing the "thanks" fluff along with other filler.  If you're going to bother editing an old post at all, definitely remove that too (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it).

Comment: `0xffffffffffffffff` is representable as a sign-extended imm32 (`-1`).   I think you made up this example without actually testing this specific constant, because gas version 2.29.1 assembles it just fine; `48 c7 45 f8 ff ff ff ff         movq   $0xffffffffffffffff,-0x8(%rbp)` (disassembly from objdump).  **If the high 32 bits weren't all copies of bit 31, it wouldn't be encodeable with a memory destination, though.**

Comment: And BTW, the AT&T mnemonic for `mov r64, imm64` is `movabs`.  Intel-syntax assemblers pick an encoding based on the constant when you use a 64-bit register destination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is that?

Because `MOV r64, imm64` is a valid x86 instruction, but `MOV r/m64, imm64` is not (there's no encoding for it).

> I see in compiled C code that in asm these numbers are split in two and two movl instructions show up.

`MOV r/m64, imm32` is a valid x86 instruction, which is why you see two of them being used to store a 64-bit immediate to memory.

> Maybe you can tell me where the mowq and other instructions are documented

In [Intel's Software Developer Manuals](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html).

Comment: Thanks, but what is the logic that this instruction isn't there?

Comment: Intel did not think that such an instruction would be very useful, so they chose not to waste a scarce instruction encoding on it.

Comment: @markgz: AMD designed the x86-64 ISA extensions, not Intel.  But yes, they decided that most 64-bit instructions would still use 32-bit immediates (sign-extended), because large constants are rare (and 64-bit addresses are normally handled by RIP-relative LEA).  But yes, the REX.W=1 version of the 5-byte `mov r32,imm32` special encoding (with the register number in the opcode byte) becomes `mov r64, imm64`, while REX.W=1 `mov r/m32, imm32` becomes `mov r/m64, sign_extended_imm32`.  There were already two different opcodes that could move an immediate to a register, so AMD took advantage.

Comment: The question is claiming use of `movl`, 32-bit bit operand-size.  Most compilers would use `mov r64, imm64` / `mov r/m64, r64`, but it's also possible to do 2x `mov r/m32, imm32`.  But you wouldn't use 2x `mov r/m64, sign_extended_imm32` like your answer suggests to store a single 64-bit value; you'd have to partially overlap them and write 4 bytes above where you want.

Comment: The whole questions is semi-bogus anyway, `movq  $0xffffffffffffffff, -8(%rbp)` is encodeable because `-1` fits in an imm32.